# How to get the correct current date from the server in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am now try to filter the data sending back to the user,

I am filtering by the date, month & year.

I got the date and month correct but the year is giving me strange result

here is my code

```
const filterByDate = (req) => {
  const match = {
      shop_id: req.params.shop_id,
    };

  let beforeString, afterString, date, filter_by, params;
 
  if (filter_by == "date") {
    beforeString = date;
    afterString = new Date(date.getTime() + 86400000);
  } else if(filter_by == "month") {
    beforeString = new Date(date.setDate(1));
    afterString = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 1);
  }else if(filter_by == "year"){
    beforeString = new Date(date.setDate(1));
    afterString = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getYear(), 1);
    console.log(afterString)
  }

  match.createdAt = {
    $gte: moment(beforeString, "YYYY/MM/DD"),
    $lt: moment(afterString, "YYYY/MM/DD"),
  };

  return match
};
```

As you can see I am console.logging the `afterString` inside the `else if` loop whenever i try to call the route.

The date its giving me back is in `2031` instead of `2021`
This happen only in the `else if year` filter

here is the console.log statement

```
2031-01-31T17:00:00.000Z
2031-01-31T17:00:00.000Z
```

Here is the route I am calling with date

`/incomes/?filter_by=year&date=2021/07/04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params for `new Date` are

```
new Date(year, monthIndex, day)
```

In the second else if, for monthIndex, you are passing in date.getYear() instead of a month value.